# OpenSUSE - Blender cannot encode or export video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, linux

I have recently installed OpenSUSE after the Windows 10 trial ran out, and I am having trouble editing video with Blender. Everything seems to be working correctly until I try to export the video. as seen in the picture, the only viable video export option is "AVI Raw". This is not optimal, as I would normally encode in H.264/AAC and export an MPEG. As you can see, neither of those options are available. In fact, there's not even an Encode tab in the Render menu.

NOTE: I HAVE tried exporting video as AVI Raw, but neither the video or audio will play in VLC. It plays like a silent audio file.

[image]

Obviously I've missed something, but finding support for the Linux version of Blender AND the video editing portion is proving difficult. Any idea why these options are unavailable?

Missing Features:
H.264 encoding /
AAC audio /
MPEG container /
The Encode tab

Comment: Where did you install blender from? It's possible that it was built without ffmpeg or something. Try downloading it from blender.org

Comment: I downloaded my version from the openSUSE-13.2-Oss repository (http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/). Just took a look at the files used to build the program and, sure enough, FFMPEG is not included. I will try building it myself and see what happens

Comment: Okay, I have downloaded the latest master from http://git.blender.org/blender.git I have built it with no major errors and I have ffmpeg installed. According to the Build doc (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/OpenSUSE/CMake), install_deps.sh should have linked ffmpeg to blender automatically. Farther down, it mentions that I may need to "Set the FFMPEG_LIBRARIES var to full paths of all needed libs (xvid, x264, etc.)". I'm not quite sure how to go about this, though.

Comment: Oh, additionally, it appears that this build no longer accepts .OGG, .MP3, or .FLAC files in the Video Sequence Editor. It gives a pop-up saying "File 'X' could not be loaded." This problem was not present previously.

Comment: Use the Frame Server feature and pipe it to a proper encoding program...